# Logout do facebook SDK 4.+

Tags: android

Tenho duas activities. LoginActivity -> esta faz o login com o facebook, funcionando normalmente. E após o login é chamada a MainActivity -> Nesta eu preciso fazer o Logout do facebook. Como é possível fazê-lo? Como trazer minhas informações login para a Main e executar o LoginManager.getInstance().logOut(); ?

Comment: Se você está utilizando um botão do facebook personalizado é dessa forma mesmo.

Comment: Está me subindo um erro MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference .. Na tela de login eu utilizei o botão do facebook da SDK